# jQuery ToolTip stops working after changing chrome tab

Tags: jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/Argus137/A44EB/971/

Here's fiddle, the code is simple:

```
$('.tt').on({
  "click": function() {
    $(this).tooltip();
    $(this).tooltip("open");
  },
  "mouseout": function() {      
     $(this).tooltip("disable");   
  }
});
```

Then the div's

```
<div class="tt" title="my title">Test</div>

<div class="tt" title="my title3">Test</div>
```

So if I change the tab on chrome and then switch the tab back, my tooltip won't work, only the last one, the first one won't.. (You can reproduce that on jsfiddle) Any ideas what causes that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.tooltip('close')` instead of `.tooltip('disable')`. I believe that that is why it no longer works after mouseout.

To address the concerns of your comment, try on your click function, check to see if it is disabled, and if so, then re-enable it.

```
$('.tt').on({
  "click": function() {
    $(this).tooltip();
    if ($(this).tooltip('option', 'disabled')) {
        $(this).tooltip('enable');
    }
    $(this).tooltip("open");
  },
  "mouseout": function() {      
     $(this).tooltip("disable");   
  }
});
```

[jQueryUI tooltip docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#method-close)

Comment: If I use 'close', then the tooltip appears after I hover on it next time instead of clicking it. Though this seems to fix the problem with it not appearing at all. I'll look into all the types of "openings" and "closings". Thanks.

Comment: ah, gotcha, i think i understand better now, you want the click to activate it.

Answer (score 0):

So after Michael's answer I indeed found out that the problem is with `.tooltip('disable')` so I inserted `.tooltip('enable')` near `.tooltip('open')`
and it now works continuessly. I don't know if this is the best way to solve the problem but it worked for me.